# universal collision detection for action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm writing a game where you have to go through a maze. I want this game to have different levels. But for each level, the maze is going to be different. So I drew other walls. But I do not want to write my collision detection method 50 times if I have 50 different levels.

I thought of a way of fixing it, but it's not working. I created a new symbol with nothing in it and named it wall. I think that I can make my wall = wall1 (another symbol I converted, and exported for as), and just do stage.addChild(wall). But I can't find a way to do that. So I need help!

Answer (score 0):

Make a generic class e.g. `Wall` and make your library symbols use that for their base class. You won't need to create them at runtime using ActionScript for this inheritance to work, you can still just place your MovieClips on the stage.

The next thing you need to do is store these Walls somewhere. Because you seem inexperienced with ActionScript, and want to avoid writing code for new levels, you can automate this process using a manager type class. We will call this class `WallManager` and it will look like this:

```
public class WallManager
{
    private static var _walls:Vector.<Wall> = new <Wall>[];

    internal static function register(wall:Wall):void
    {
        _walls.push(wall);
    }

    public static function reset():void
    {
        _walls = new <Wall>[];
    }

    public static function get walls():Vector.<Wall>{ return _walls; }
}
```

Then we'll create your `Wall` class. Within the constructor for this class, we will automatically have the Wall add itself into the `WallManager` listing:

```
public class Wall extends Sprite
{
    public function Wall()
    {
        WallManager.register(this);
    }

    public function touchingMouse(mouseX:int, mouseY:int):Boolean
    {
        // For this example I am checking for collisions with the
        // mouse pointer. Replace this function with your own collision
        // logic for whatever it is that is supposed to collide with
        // these walls.

        if(parent === null) return false;

        var bounds:Rectangle = getBounds(parent);
        return bounds.contains(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
}
```

This setup is not 'best practice', but it is suitable in your situation because your project seems small, you appear to be working on it alone, it's simple and it gets the job done.

At the end of each level, use `WallManager.reset()` to remove the walls from the previous level. For checking collisions across all walls, just use a loop like this:

```
for each(var i:Wall in WallManager.walls)
{
    var collision:Boolean = i.touchingMouse(mouseX, mouseY);

    if(collision)
    {
        // There was a collision.
        //
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make one MovieClip with 50 frames saying `stop()` on the first frame and do your code like this:

```
    private var wallnum:int;

public function Main()
{
   stop();
   wallnum = 1;
   var wallobj = new Wall();
   addChild(wallobj);
   wallobj.gotoAndStop(wallnum);
}
```

For collision detection, I recommend Pixel Perfect Collision Detection  (https://code.google.com/p/master-air-controller/source/browse/trunk/master-air-controller/src/PixelPerfectCollisionDetection.as?spec=svn6&r=6)